# IPsec certificate is invalid at the moment

Tags: azure

We have a AZURE Connect to an outside Company. (This works fine for a while.)

On the Azure Diagnostics  the only on yellow point is:

“An IPsec certificate is invalid at the moment, Connect will try to update the certificate, please ensure that the machine is connected to the internet.”

The connection is disconnected in case on wrong certificates,

The Server have full Internet access. How I can update the Certificate manually?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the Connect endpoint software to the latest version: [Upgrade to the latest Connect endpoint software now](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_azure_connect_team_blog/archive/2012/08/31/upgrade-to-the-latest-connect-endpoint-software-now.aspx)

> On 10/28/2012, the current CA certificate used by Windows Azure
>   Connect endpoint software will expire. To continue to use Windows
>   Azure Connect after this date, Connect endpoint software on your
>   Windows Azure roles and on-premises machines must be upgraded to the
>   latest version.

Comment: Hi, i get this on the link   The website has encountered a problem  

[Error number: 8DDD0024] 
The update requested could not be found.  I seach for this on Google and all links seam to be wrong.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem there. Have you tried to download it from the old portal? Virtual Network > Install Local Endpoint